# How to set NSFetchRequest propertiesToFetch with a custom function using NSExpression

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsfetchrequest, nsexpression

I have a attribute "message" of type String in CoreData Entity, which stores text and sometimes including URLs . Now i need to fetch all the url's from the entity.

```
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format:"message CONTAINS[cd] %@", "http")
    let fetchRequest = self.getfetchRequest(entityName: "Messages", sectionKey:nil, predicate:predicate)
    let expressionDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
    expressionDescription.name = "urlFromMsg"
    expressionDescription.expressionResultType = .StringAttributeType
    let expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "toUrl", arguments: [NSExpression(forKeyPath: "message")])

    expressionDescription.expression = expression
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [expressionDescription]
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType
```

Here toUrl is a custom function that extends String.

```
extension String {
    func toUrl()->[String]?{
        let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Link.rawValue)
        let matches = detector.matchesInString(self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.utf16.count))
        var urls = [String]()
        for match in matches {
            urls.append((self as NSString).substringWithRange(match.range))
        }
        return urls
    }
}
```

i am getting crash at this line

```
let expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "toUrl", arguments: [NSExpression(forKeyPath: "message")])
```

How to set the custom method properly in NSExpression.

Comment: see http://useyourloaf.com/blog/core-data-queries-using-expressions/ - but not all custom functions are CD compatible..

Answer (score 1):

When using a custom `NSExpression` in a fetch request and a SQLite-backed Core Data store, Core Data attempts to translate the expression into a SQL query. That helps with performance, but it means that not all valid `NSExpression`s are valid for use with Core Data.

Specifically, an `NSExpression` that relies on a custom function can't be used with a Core Data fetch, because Core Data can't translate arbitrary code into SQL.

You'll need to drop this `NSExpression` from the fetch and convert to URLs using the results of the fetch. You could also switch to a non-SQLite Core Data store, but that's generally much worse for a variety of reasons unless your persistent store contains very small amounts of data.